# Jakarta 9 Initialcontext is missing

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish

I'm in the process of upgrading my webapp from JEE8 to Jakarta 9.

It is based on EJBs and everything works like a charm in JEE 8 and Payara 5.x.

But when I try to move to Jakarta 9 and Glassfish 6 i face a JNDI lookup problem.

the code is:

```
 try {
        InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
        mailer = (ReviewerInviteEmail) ic.lookup("java:global/DruidAdmin/ReviewerInviteEmail!dk.druid.mailers.ReviewerInviteEmail");
       .
       .
       more code here
    } catch (NamingException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(InviteReviewersController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (MailTypeNotDefinedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(InviteReviewersController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        addErrorMessage(ex.getMessage());
    }
```

In JEE 8 it works but in Jakarta 9 InitialContext doesn't exist. Or at least I cant use it as shown here.

How is this look up done in Jakarta 9?

thanks
Kim

Comment: Is this a compile time problem or a runtime problem? If it is runtime problem please add the stack trace to your question.

Comment: Thanks for replying. It is a compile time problem.

Comment: `javax.naming.InitialContext` is part of the JDK, it is in the java.naming module. Your problem must be elsewhere.